# Apache Airflow - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, airflow

I am running apache-airflow locally on docker. I am not able to import selenium into one of my dag which involves scraping data from the web periodically. I ran pip install command in the console which returned requirement already satisfied. I read the official documentation on Module Management of apache airflow but still cannot figure out.

I tried modifying the sys.path variable as shown in the code below but still got the same error

```
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\DELL\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages")
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select,WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Any hint that would point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide your Dockerfile or docker-compose file? How do you start your containers. selenium should be installed inside of your container in order for DAG to be able to import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is like a "computer" inside your computer. If you are not entering the docker container first, your `pip install` is installing `selenium` in your computer, not in the docker where Airflow is running.

You can enter the container with `docker exec -it container_name bash` and then run the `pip install` there. Or better yet, create a requirements file and share it as a volume in your airflow docker-compose file